# AngularJS Date Format Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

On trying the [inbuilt angularjs date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to format the date string, I am not getting the formatted date for "2016-05-17 14:45:59+04",

See the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/VzRpNFkrWasv3nPlIQyg?p=preview ,

Please help me in understanding why it is working and I am getting the proper date object when I parse the string "2016-05-17 14:45:59+04" using see the screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example101-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
</head>
<body ng-app="">

<span ng-non-bindable>{{2016-05-17 14:45:59+04 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>:
<span>{{'2016-05-17 14:45:59+04' | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span><br>

</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Comment: Use Javascript `Date` object instead of passing it as a string to filter.

Comment: @Yogesh: Thanks Yogesh It works. I created custom filter and parsed before giving to the inbuilt date filter like "return $filter('date')(Date.parse(dateString), 'dd-mm-yyyy' );"

Comment: @Yogesh: put it in answer I will mark it.

Comment: Posted it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript `Date` object instead of passing it as a string.

**// somewhere in the controller**

```
$scope.dt = new Date('2016-05-17 14:45:59+04');
```

**// in html**

```
<span>{{dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
```

You can also write custom filter to do it, which you have already done.

**Key point here is using Javascript `Date` object**

Comment: What a surprise it works with Date. It solves the question, but does not answer it. Of course you're right, it's not good style to work with string literals to represent dates.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) compliant date/time format:

```
<span>{{'2016-05-17T14:45:59+04:00' | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [link that you provided](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), under Usage > Arguments:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

So, choose a different format for your date string, for example:

```
2016-05-17T14:45:59.000+0400
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to avoid being forced to do `new Date()` in your controller each time you have to handle date, you can use a filter that will automatically transform your date into a `new Date()`:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .filter('toNewDate', toNewDate);

function toNewDate() {
    return toNewDateFilter;

    ////////////////

    function toNewDateFilter(date) {
        return new Date(date);
    }

}
```

Now you can use it through your application and save lots of time (e.g. when you receive dates from webservices):

```
<span class="date">{{post.created_at| toNewDate | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}</span>
```